# Accessing Data Member

Tags: javascript

I've create a namespace like the one below.

```
var Constants = {
    Foo: 'bar',
    SomeVar: {
       key: 'value'
    }
};
```

What I want to do is:

```
var Constants = {
    Foo: 'bar',
    SomeVar: {
       key: Constants.Foo + 'value' // Notice the Constants.Foo
    }
};
```

What I want to do is be able to use the value of **Constants.Foo** to create a value for **SomeVar**. However this throws an error in Firebug.

So I'm wondering, how do I access the value of Foo inside the Constants namespace; and also, I've been reading a few articles on encapsulation in Javascript (like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108786/Encapsulation-in-JavaScript) one), is it possible to access value of Foo without having to do Constants.Foo? Perhaps some sort of way to preserve a reference to the namespace's *this* keyword and then I can do something like *thisParent.Foo*.

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

This is the error I'm getting by the way:

> TypeError: Constants is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. An object *literal* doesn’t have a name until you assign it to something, and by then, it’s too late. Object literals aren't functions, either, so there’s no contextual keyword you could use; `this` would still be whatever it was in the containing function. Adding the property afterwards is the only way.

```
var Constants = {
    Foo: 'bar',
    SomeVar: {}
};

Constants.SomeVar.key = Constants.Foo + 'value';
```

And no, a namespace is not a thing in JavaScript. That is an object. Nothing more.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Thank you. This helped clarify things!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Constants` doesn't exist until the assignment is executed, which is after the object is constructed. You could do something like this (an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)):

```
var Constants = (function() {
    self = { Foo : 'bar' };
    self.SomeVar = self.Foo + 'value';
    return self;
}());
```

Comment: You can’t assign to `this`.

Comment: Would I still be able to do Constants.Foo or would I then have to do Constants().Foo?

Comment: @minitech - Oops. Changed it to `self`. Too much Java. :(

Comment: @ThePedestrian - It would be a regular object. You would do `Constants.Foo`. Just use `self` instead of `this` (`this` has special meaning).

Comment: @zerkms - Ah, you mean for `self`? It may seem so, but it works fine without it. (Actually, it won't work if you _do_ try to use `var self`.)

Comment: @zerkms: `self` is implicitly the window, but **only in browsers**. It is weird. But yes, it will leak a global.

Comment: @minitech - Hm. I must have had a typo when I tested it. Executing the function twice seems to return different objects, with or without `var`. What do you mean that it will leak a global?

Comment: @TedHopp: If you don’t declare `self`, it will overwrite the global `self`. This is usually not good, and it would break in strict mode if it weren’t for the oddity that is the predefined `self = window`.

Comment: @minitech - Got it. I suppose it would be best to use a name like `me`.